# Android app development issue - Where to ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I need advice on how I can design an Android browser with an on-the-fly HEVC conversion capability to reduce the file size of media files.

Is there a Stack Exchange site appropriate for this question?

Comment: So... Are you looking for a site recommendation for where to ask this question?

Comment: Actually I just need as much info on what I need as per tools, tutorial and resources to design my Android web browser

Comment: You're on the wrong part of Stack Exchange. This is the meta site for discussion about SE. And I'm not even sure this is an acceptable question even on the correct site.

Comment: Ok then direct me the proper place to ask my question please

Comment: I'm not sure but I've edited your question to ask where this question is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks alot  I appreciate ur input

Comment: Nowhere on SE.  If you want tools, tutorials and resources use a search engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is very broad. I am quite familiar with [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and I am sure this question would get closed very quickly.

The problem with your question is that it will take book lengths to answer your question and it actually needs a software architect to look at the requirements and make a design how to implement that. That is an entire software development cycle you are asking about.

If your primarily concern is how to build that conversion, I would suggest to do some digging how the compression algorithms work or some libraries for you to do that. The first can be on-topic on Stack Overflow if you show your current attempt in code and speech and your exact problem. Recommending tools isn't allowed there, possibly on other sites, such as [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/), but I am not a user there so check out their help center to see if your specific tool recommendation question is on-topic there.

Comment: I understand as u explained that my question is too broad, I will try to refine it abit more